# jq parse json with stream flag into different json file

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have a json file as below called data.json, I want to parse the data with **jq** tool in **streaming mode**(do not load the whole file into memory), because the **real data have 20GB**

the streaming mode in jq seems to add a flag --stream and it will parse the json file row by row

```
{
  "id": {
    "bioguide": "E000295",
    "thomas": "02283",
    "govtrack": 412667,
    "opensecrets": "N00035483",
    "lis": "S376"
  },
  "bio": {
    "gender": "F",
    "birthday": "1970-07-01"
  },
  "tooldatareports": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "tooldata": [
        {
          "toolid": 12345,
          "data": [
            {
              "time": "2021-01-01",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-02",
              "value": 10
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-03",
              "value": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "toolid": 12346,
          "data": [
            {
              "time": "2021-01-01",
              "value": 10
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-02",
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-03",
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The final result I hope it can become as below

A list contains two dict, each dict contain 2 keys

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2021-01-01",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-02",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-03",
        "value": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2021-01-01",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-02",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-03",
        "value": 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For this problem, I use the below command line to get a result, but it still has some differences.

cat data.json | jq --stream 'select(.[0][0]=="tooldatareports" and .[0][2]=="tooldata" and .[1]!=null) | .'

1. the result is not a list contain a lot of dict
2. for each time and value are separate in the different list

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: Aside, `cat foo | bar` is _always_ better replaced with `bar <foo`.

Comment: Moving towards trying to answer your question, though... could you try to build a clearer [mre]? There's enough data here that it isn't obvious what the difference between your expected and actual outputs are. Simplifying should help to make that more visually clear.

Comment: Taking out the things you tried is really not what I was suggesting. Simplifying the data to be the shortest possible dataset so people can see at a glance what the difference between actual and expected output is what would do more good in making this answerable. Showing what you tried is important and valuable (so is showing your _actual_ output from those attempts so it can be compared to the expected output; but to make that actual output easy to understand and compare, the sample data should be as short as possible).

Comment: ...so, f/e, can you make sample input that demonstrates the problem fit in a single line of JSON, and provide both desired corresponding sample output, and the code you're currently trying with its _actual_ sample output to compare?

Comment: ("some differences" doesn't tell us which _specific_ things are different between your actual and expected result, so it's not describing the exact problem you want solved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not use `truncate_stream`:

```
jq -n --stream '
 [fromstream( 
   inputs
   | (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix
   | select($ix)
   | .[0] |= .[$ix:] )]
' input.json
```

Comment: Thanks, Any idea to add "bioguide" in each dict?

Comment: It sounds like yiu have a new question, so it might make sense to ask a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step-by-step explanation of peak's answers.

First let's convert the json to stream.

https://jqplay.org/s/VEunTmDSkf

```
[["id","bioguide"],"E000295"]
[["id","thomas"],"02283"]
[["id","govtrack"],412667]
[["id","opensecrets"],"N00035483"]
[["id","lis"],"S376"]
[["id","lis"]]
[["bio","gender"],"F"]
[["bio","birthday"],"1970-07-01"]
[["bio","birthday"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"name"],"A"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"toolid"],12345]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"value"],1]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"time"],"2021-01-02"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"value"],10]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"time"],"2021-01-03"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"value"],5]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"toolid"],12346]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"value"],10]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"time"],"2021-01-02"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"value"],100]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"time"],"2021-01-03"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"value"],50]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata"]]
[["tooldatareports",0]]
[["tooldatareports"]]
```

Now do `.[0]` to extract the `path` portion of stream.

https://jqplay.org/s/XdPrp8RuEj

```
["id","bioguide"]
["id","thomas"]
["id","govtrack"]
["id","opensecrets"]
["id","lis"]
["id","lis"]
["bio","gender"]
["bio","birthday"]
["bio","birthday"]
["tooldatareports",0,"name"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"toolid"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"time"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"time"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"time"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"toolid"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"time"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"time"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"time"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"value"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data"]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1]
["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata"]
["tooldatareports",0]
["tooldatareports"]
```

Let me first quickly explain `index\1`.

`index("data")` of `[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]` is 4 since that is the index of the first occurrence of "data".

Knowing that let's now do `.[0] | index("data")`.

https://jqplay.org/s/ny0bV1xEED

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
null
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
null
null
null
null
```

As you can see in our case the indexes are either 4 or null. We want to filter each `input` such that the corresponding index is not null. Those are the `input` that have "data" as part of their path.

`(.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix)` does just that.  Remember that each `$ix` is mapped to each **input**. So only input with their `$ix` being not null are displayed.

For example see https://jqplay.org/s/NwcD7_USZE Here `inputs | select(null)` gives no output but `inputs | select(true)` outputs every `input`.

These are the filtered stream:

https://jqplay.org/s/SgexvhtaGe

```
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"value"],1]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"time"],"2021-01-02"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"value"],10]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",1,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"time"],"2021-01-03"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"value"],5]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",2]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"value"],10]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",0,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"time"],"2021-01-02"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"value"],100]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",1,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"time"],"2021-01-03"]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"value"],50]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2,"value"]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data",2]]
[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",1,"data"]]
```

Before we go further let's review *update assignment*.

Have a look at https://jqplay.org/s/g4P6j8f9FG

Let's say we have input `[["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]`.

Then filter `.[0] |= .[4:]` produces `[["data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]`.

Why?

Remember that right hand side (`.[4:]`) **inherits** the context of the left hand side(`.[0]`). So in this case it has the effect of updating the path `["tooldatareports",0,"tooldata",0,"data",0,"time"]` to `["data",0,"time"]`.

Let's move on then.

So `(.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix:]` has the output:

https://jqplay.org/s/AwcQpVyHO2

```
[["data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]
[["data",0,"value"],1]
[["data",0,"value"]]
[["data",1,"time"],"2021-01-02"]
[["data",1,"value"],10]
[["data",1,"value"]]
[["data",2,"time"],"2021-01-03"]
[["data",2,"value"],5]
[["data",2,"value"]]
[["data",2]]
[["data"]]
[["data",0,"time"],"2021-01-01"]
[["data",0,"value"],10]
[["data",0,"value"]]
[["data",1,"time"],"2021-01-02"]
[["data",1,"value"],100]
[["data",1,"value"]]
[["data",2,"time"],"2021-01-03"]
[["data",2,"value"],50]
[["data",2,"value"]]
[["data",2]]
[["data"]]
```

Now all we need to do is convert this stream back to json.

https://jqplay.org/s/j2uyzEU_Rc

`[fromstream(inputs)]` gives:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2021-01-01",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-02",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-03",
        "value": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "time": "2021-01-01",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-02",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "time": "2021-01-03",
        "value": 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the output we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The following produces the required output:

```
jq -n --stream '
  [{data: fromstream(5|truncate_stream(inputs))}]
' input.json
```

Needless to say, there are other variations ...